# I'm new to Calc 3 and I don't know the difference between ijk and <> for vectors

Tags: vectors

Title

I am quite sure that each have their uses but I am confused exactly when and how to use either form

i+j+k
or
<1,1,1>

Thanks

Comment: Notation is almost always a matter of preference. You should use whichever one you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both ideas, if I read you right, are expressing vectors in three dimensions in terms of three basis vectors. In one case these are called $i, j, k$ and in the other $\langle 1,0,0\rangle; \langle 0,1,0\rangle; \langle 0,0,1\rangle$. The obvious mapping between the two systems is an isomorphism, the two systems are completely equivalent, and the notation to use is that which is most convenient.

Alternatively the notation your tutor uses and which might appear in your exam should be preferred.

You will find that there are other notations too (!) because vectors are versatile things and crop up in different contexts and the notations developed from the contexts before a general notation could be agreed. The second notation $\langle 1,0,0\rangle$ etc specifies components in a convenient way which is easier to generalise than the other, and is more readily evolved into the expression of linear mappings (with respect to a basis) as matrices.

Answer (score 0):

${\bf i},{\bf j},{\bf k}$ is the standard basis of the 3d space, and the *coordinates* of the vector $a{\bf i}+b{\bf j}+c{\bf k}$ are $(a,b,c)$ *with respect to the standard basis*.

That ${\bf i},{\bf j},{\bf k}$ is a *basis* means that every vector in the space can be uniquely written in the above form for some real numbers $a,b,c$.